# How to move packages from build to devel folder

Tags: ros, catkin-make, devel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot figure out why some of my packages end up inside the `devel` folder other stay inside the `build` folder (including their targets)
[Doc](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Build_Space) just says:

> The location of the devel space is controlled by a catkin specific CMake variable called `CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX`, and it defaults to `<build space>/develspace`.

How to Configure the package.xml or CMakeLists.txt properly? [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MzoTKF7WAiRDBlMWJCaGNrX3M/view?usp=sharing) for more info on the files

##EDIT addon
##1.
I changed the order  and It works.
I thought this is the purpose of that command:

```
## Libraries are installed in a lib/ directory shared by all packages in entire ROS distro
 install(TARGETS my_test_lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION})

## List all your executables as TARGETS to be installed in a per-package directory 
#   not the distro’s global bin/ directory
  install(TARGETS talker listener add_two_ints_server add_two_ints_client
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

##2.
Furthermore the  tutorial uses find_package with genmsg but does not mention any build_depend in the xml? Is there a difference to message_generation?  I get this if I use message_generation and not genmsg:

```
/home/baum/catkin_ws/src/test_my_env/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp:2:36: fatal error: test_my_env/AddTwoInts.h: No such file or directory
```

#include "test_my_env/AddTwoInts.h"
I feel like all  `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS`  need to be mentioned in the run_depend tag in xml 
##3.
Do I need rospy also I only use roscpp. In the tutorials its often present also its c++ tut. (like addtwoints serv/client)
##4.  SOLVED: Argl... I missed the header name AddTwoInts in the variable declaration test_my_env::AddTwoInts::Request 
I moved the package to another workspace and now it says:

```
 [ 36%] Building CXX object test_my_env/CMakeFiles/my_test_lib.dir/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp.o
 [ 40%] Built target polled_camera_generate_messages_eus
 [ 42%] Building CXX object test_my_env/CMakeFiles/my_test_lib.dir/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp.o
 /home/baum/catkin_ws/src/test_my_env/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp:5:10: error: ‘Request’ is not a member of ‘test_my_env’
  bool add(test_my_env::Request  &req,
                 ^
/home/baum/catkin_ws/src/test_my_env/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp:5:33: error: ‘req’ was not declared in this scope
bool add(test_my_env::Request  &req,
                     ^
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225447/how-to-move-packages-from-build-to-devel-folder/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CMake call to `catkin_package(...)` sets the destination folder for binaries, so you need to make sure that your CMakeLists.txt is ordered so that all of your `add_executable()` and `add_library()` calls are **AFTER** your call to `catkin_package()`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-31**:
Just to add to this: order matters in `CMakeLists.txt` with catkin. See [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Overall_Structure_and_Ordering).